# Why am i not retrieving rows when the user has both the admin and support role?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query builder:

```php
return $builder
            ->when($authUser->hasRole('admin'), function (Builder $q) use ($authUser) {
                $q->whereHas('users', function (Builder $builder) use ($authUser) {
                    $builder->where('users.id', $authUser->id);
                });
            })
            ->when($authUser->hasRole('support'), function (Builder $q) {
                $q->whereHas('users', function (Builder $q2) {
                    $q2->where('support_access', true);
                });
            })
            ->when($authUser->hasRole('owner'), function (Builder $q) use ($authUser) {
                $q
                    ->where(function (Builder $builder) use ($authUser) {
                        $builder
                            ->whereIn('device_id', $authUser->company->devices->pluck('id'))
                            ->orWhereIn('id', $authUser->runs()->pluck('runs.id'));
                    });
            })
            ->when($authUser->hasRole('viewer'), function (Builder $q) use ($authUser) {
                $q->whereIn('id', $authUser->runs->pluck('id'));
            });
```

What is supposed to happen is that if the user has the support role it will retrieve all runs where support_access is set to true. When the user has the admin role it does not do this. But when the user has both the admin and support role it should retrieve those runs if support_access is true for those runs.

The first cases work but my user is not getting any runs when they have both the admin and support role. How could I edit thuis query builder so it takes this third scenario into account?

Comment: Just curious, what's the exact difference between the `admin` and `support` role and how is the hierarchy between the two? Wouldn't the `admin` role inherit the `support` role by default? Could you also clarify which (if any) packages you are using to implement the role/permission scheme?

Comment: You would think so but the client doesn't want admin to have support role permissions by default. I actually just manage to fix it, I'll post the answer.

Comment: Gekkenwerk .. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to figure out how to do this:

````php
return $builder
            ->where(function(Builder$builder)  use ($authUser) {
              $builder
                  ->when($authUser->hasRole('admin'), function (Builder $q) use ($authUser) {
                      $q->orWhereHas('users', function (Builder $builder) use ($authUser) {
                          $builder->where('users.id', $authUser->id);
                      });
                  })
                  ->when($authUser->hasRole('support'), function (Builder $q) {
                      $q->orWhereHas('users', function (Builder $q2) {
                          $q2->where('support_access', true);
                      });
                  })
                  ->when($authUser->hasRole('owner'), function (Builder $q) use ($authUser) {
                      $q
                          ->orWhere(function (Builder $builder) use ($authUser) {
                              $builder
                                  ->whereIn('device_id', $authUser->company->devices->pluck('id'))
                                  ->orWhereIn('id', $authUser->runs()->pluck('runs.id'));
                          });
                  })
                  ->when($authUser->hasRole('viewer'), function (Builder $q) use ($authUser) {
                      $q->orWhereIn('id', $authUser->runs->pluck('id'));
                  });
            });
    ```
````